# How i know my local IP is active or not in nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ip

I have some Local network IP. Now i want to know these IP is active or not. How can i do that with nodejs. I have tried but don't know the proper approach to get it.

```
const keepAliveAgent = new http.Agent({ keepAlive: true });
```

If `keepAlive` is `true` then my IP is active, am i right? Any help will be appreciable. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by "active"? You want one machine to track to check if another machine on the network is up? on a specific port?

Comment: @developer82 Yes, want to check other machine is up or not.

Comment: You can try to ping the other machine (https://github.com/nospaceships/node-net-ping) but of course you need to make sure that pining is not blocked. Or you can try to open a socket to a port you know is opened on the other machine.

Comment: @developer82 is it possible without pinging?

Comment: As I mentioned, you can connect to a port you know should be open. If the connection is successful then the machine is online.